# How to type typescript function static variable

Tags: typescript, function, static, typescript-typings

In Javascript (and Typescript) you can statically add variables to a function, since its a first class object. I want to do this to add metadata to the function. How can i type this to enforce that the function has a certain static variable?

```
function doThing() {
   console.log('thing done!')
}
doThing.id = 'myThingId';

function dispatch(func: Function | { id:string }) { // <-- what is this type, 
  console.log('this should be strictly typed', func.id);
}
```

In the example here ive done: Function | { id:string } to say that its a union of a function and an object with 'id' - but this doesnt work. What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a [Call Signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#call-signatures):

```js
type DescribableFunction = {
  id: string;
  (): void;
};


function dispatch(func: DescribableFunction) {
  console.log('this should be strictly typed', func.id);
}
```